# How can transient variables be used in a class that implements Parcelable?

Tags: java, android, class, parcelable, transient

I need to understand if a transient variable inside a class that implements Parcelable interface should be read from the parcel in **modelClass(Parcel parcel)** method or written to the parcel in **writeToParcel(Parcel parcel,int i)** . Can anyone provide me with a class implementation with a transient variable in it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The "transient"-keyword has no effect on parcelable objects. There is no automation in reading and writing the fields in a parcelable object, so there is no ready made code that would take it into account. Any possible choice of special processing for transient fields is completely up to the person designing the class.

Specification (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3) says "Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part of the persistent state of an object" so if you *really* want to go by the book you should not write them. But, as I said, since the reading and writing is done mechanically inside the class, the transient keyword doesn't make much sense.

Comment: When implementing parcelable there are two methods called writeToParcel and reading from parcel. I had a doubt whether transient data should be written to the parcel which would be serialized.Since reading a parcel always ends in populating a transient variable with null value so writing transient to a parcel is necessary or not?

Comment: Reading a parcel does not populate the transient variable to null. Creating the object instance initializes it to null (or whatever the default value for the type is) and reading the parcel just leaves it as it was after initialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee implements Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private transient String confidentialInfo;

    //Setters and Getters
}
```

Comment: before passing this class to other class if some other threads approaches it and changes the value what would happend?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add transient keyword before data type while declaring variable.

```
class Parcel implements Parcelable{
   private Integer checkinId;
   private transient String someCode;

   //// some methods
}

interface Parcelable implements{
  // some methods
}
```

Comment: When implementing parcelable there are two methods called writeToParcel and reading from parcel. I had a doubt whether transient data should be written to the parcel which would be serialized.Since reading a parcel always ends in populating a transient variable with null value so writing transient to a parcel is necessary or not?